# How to export embedded powerBi report with current view / default view in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to implement PowerBI export to pdf or ppt in react, but the point at which I am having problems is exporting the report as the current view after the user has filtered or made changes.

Comment: You must use [BookmarksManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/bookmarksmanager.bookmarksmanager) class to [capture the current state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/showcase-bookmarks#capture-a-view-and-save-it-to-the-bookmarks-list) and then pass this state when calling the export API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can you take a look on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/end-user-powerpoint
This is exactly what I am trying to achieve @AndreyNikolov

Comment: @Harmattan, Can you reframe your question clearly ? From what I understand, you can follow the steps mentioned by Andrey. The link you pointed it is exporting the Report from powerbi service. Not sure, If I get you, we follow [ExportReporttoFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to) in embedded. firstly, Are you able to export report to pdf in react successfully ?